# Find a process by windowclass name and window name but what if wname was changed

Tags: c#, process, system.diagnostics

I have a function for finding a process by windowclass name and window name but sometimes the user is changing the windowname and my function does nothing.

Is there any other way of finding the process?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `System.Diagnostics.Process` class to find the process, Then you can find using WindowName, Handle, Module etc.

```
var process = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("MyProcess").FirstOrDefault();

var process = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcesses().FirstOrDefault(p => p.Modules[0].ModuleName == "MyModule");

var process = Process.GetProcesses().FirstOrDefault(p => p.MainWindowTitle == "NotePad");
if (process != null)
{
    SetWindowPos(process.MainWindowHandle);
}
```

Etc.

Comment: The process name is being changed at each execution and your code wont help.